# Generate a link if a product number begins with XYZ

Tags: eval

I'm not a developer but we have it set up here so that when a customer orders certain products in Linnworks, a link gets included in their e-mail receipt.

This currently works.

```
EVAL{BEGIN}IIF["[{ORDERITEMS.SKU}]"="XYZ1234", "Click here for <a href='HTTP://LINK'> guide</a>", ""]{END}
```

It gives a link if the item SKU perfectly matches, but what do I write if I want it to match if the sku STARTS WITH "XYZ" and allow for any combination of numbers after that? 
Thanks.

Comment: Whatever this code is, it is not java.

Comment: Youre right. It may be c#

Comment: Yeah.. this isn't C# either.  At least not any C# I'm familiar with.

Comment: Agree with others this is not c# but just because I was curious i googled EVAL{BEGIN}IIF and came up with [this link](https://www.linnworks.com/Doc/Template_Designer_Expressions_Conditional_Formatting) Might help you.

Comment: Wow thanks, guess its a custom language for linnworks. Thanks, I tried googling the same thing and found nothing